# Find Regex matches inside and outside of brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I hope you can help me with the following problem.

One of following example strings may be given:

```
aaa
<bbb>
aaa<bbb>
<bbb>aaa
aaa<bbb><ccc>
<bbb>aaa<ccc>
<bbb><ccc>aaa
```

I'm searching for a regular expression that matches to any of those possibilities:

```
aaa
<bbb>
<ccc>
```

What I've learned so far: With `<.*?>` I can match the parts with the brackets, but the string "aaa" bothers me and I don't get it how to make this also a separate match.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you in advance for your appreciated help!

Best regards,

Rafael

Comment: It appears you wish to parse XML or HTML with regular expressions. That approach has [unfortunate effects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392). Have you considered using an XML or HTML  parser instead?

Comment: Hello Richard, It's not really html/xml, I'm trying to parse. It's just a string, that can have normal text or a notation for commands which are inside the brackets. And depending on what's inside the string I want to call separate functions.

Comment: Could you provide a *real* example string and add a language tag to your question?

Comment: Hello Casimir. Here is an example string: `Is this my string? Yeah, this is my String!<CLICK>`

Answer (score 0):

Could just [add alternation](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qV2qV9/1):

```
<[^>]*>|[^<]+
```

Also changed `.*?` to `[^>]*` as of better performance and no worries about using `s` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Further use [*capturing groups* to separate matches](https://regex101.com/r/oR0bS2/1) if desired.